# How to templating a class constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017

I learned how to use template and it can save a lot of time, but when I try to use template with constructor, it gives errors, and I don't know how to fix the error.

My project contain...

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    c a(1);
    c b(a);
    a.f(2);
    b.f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class c {
public:
    template<typename T>
    c(const T&);
    ~c();
    template<typename T>
    void f(const T&);
private:
    uint64_t data;
};
                              //Constructors
template<typename T>
inline c::c(const T& input) {
    data = input;
}
template<>
inline c::c<c>(const c& input) {  //This line produced errors
    data = input.data;
}
                              //Destructor
inline c::~c() {}
                              //Functions
template<typename T>
inline void c::f(const T& input){  //Magic function
    cout << (data += input) << endl;
}
template<>
inline void c::f<c>(const c& input){  //Magic function
    cout << (data += input.data) << endl;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the errors are...

```
C2988 unrecognizable template declaration/definition
C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
C7525 inline variables require at least '/std:c++17'
C2350 'c::{ctor}' is not a static member
C2513 'c::{ctor}': no variable declared before '='
C2059 syntax error: '<'
C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C2447 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Somehow constructor doesn't work properly but function does.

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: the ; at the end of the declaration of class c

Comment: Can you label the lines that the errors refer to, please?

Comment: Not sure what you expect from `template<> c::c<c>(const c& input)`.

Comment: You already have correct constructor `template<typename T>
c::c(const T& input)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, but I want specific type of constructor & function like string and own class because `uint64_t = string` will produce an error and same as `uint64_t = class`, so I created specific type of constructor & function to process it, but only constructor produce errors only

Comment: Note that your `template<typename T>
void f(const T& input)` is unrelated to `c::f` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Ok, you want to **specialize** constructor the same way you specialize a method. but your specialization result in copy constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ohhh... Okey, then is there a way to **specialize** constructor and copy constructor?

Comment: You way would be correct if you didn't use `c` as specialization.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
class c
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    c(const T&);

    c(const c&) = default;

    template<typename T>
    void f(const T&);

    void f(const c&);
private:
    uint64_t data;
};

template<typename T>
c::c(const T& input) : data(input) {}

template<typename T>
void c::f(const T& input) {  //Magic function
    data += input;
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

inline void c::f(const c& input) {  //Magic function
    data += input.data;
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @user463035818 I don't know... But @Jarod42 , this code, `data(input)`, the `input` automatically access `input.data` if the class is same??

Comment: copy constructor is a special member and would not be your template method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, You just can't make constructors with templates, consider to make whole class templated for constructors.

```
    template <typename T>
    class
    {
       ...
       c<T>() = default; // for example
       c<T>(const c& input) {...}
       ...
    }

    int main()
    {
        c<int>* a = new c<int>();
    }
```